# android app crashes when i send push notification using pushbots services

Tags: android, crash, google-cloud-messaging, push

I have tried to implement push notification in my android app using pushbots services.The app opens well. But when i send a push notification from pushbots services, the app crashes. I am unable to resolve the issue. Here is my mainactivity.java

```
import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
ActionBar.TabListener
{    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)      {super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Pushbots.sharedInstance().init(this);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {    }
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
```

Here is my pushbots.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
 <!-- Pushbots Application ID  -->
 <string name="pb_appid">124556532</string>
 <!-- GCM Sender ID -->
 <string name="pb_senderid">axsd1244</string>
 <!-- Pushbots Log Level  log Tag "PB2" -->
 <string name="pb_logLevel">DEBUG</string>
 </resources>
```

Here is my manifest file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.codes.pushnotification.app" >
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 <permission    android:name="com.codes.pushnotification.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"   android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 <uses-permission  android:name="com.codes.pushnotification.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
 <!-- This app has permission to register and receive dataf message. -->
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"   />

 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="com.codes.pushnotification.app.MESSAGE" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
 <receiver
   android:name="com.pushbots.google.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action         android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.codes.pushnotification.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.pushbots.push.DefaultPushHandler" />
    <service android:name="com.pushbots.push.GCMIntentService" />
```

Comment: what error is thrown when it crashes?

Comment: As soon as i click on the "send a push" button on the pushbots dashboard, "Unfortunately, pushbotsApp has stopped." is thrown on my mobile phone device.